# Firefox console getting 'SyntaxError: illegal character

Tags: javascript, firefox

My script is as follows:

```
<script>
    var lastTime = 0; 
    function loop(time) {
        console.log(time);
        var delay = time–lastTime; 
        var fps = 1000/delay; 
        console.log(delay + ' ms');
        updateAnimation(); 
        mozRequestAnimationFrame(loop); 
        lastTime = time;
        } 
    //loop(200000);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
</script>
```

When I run it under firefox with the Web console feature - I get:

> SyntaxError: illegal character

on the line

> var delay = time–lastTime;

Whats wrong with that line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably copy pasted this from a WordPress blog or another website that translates characters into "pretty characters". Switch the `–` character out with a dash instead `-`.

Answer (score 6):

Your dash is character code `U+2013`, also called *em dash*, translated to an HTML entity it would be `&ndash;`.

You should use the normal `U+002D` or a *hyphen minus*.

[This site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) has a lot of good information for you regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the dash in

> var delay = time–lastTime;

isn't a minus sign. Try replacing it with `-`.

Answer (score 2):

You copied and pasted from somewhere. Try using the `-(minus)` symbol. Because `time–lastTime` doesn't contain minus symbol

```
time-lastTime; // use - (minus) sybmol
```